# How to use the same action/template for a get and a post?

Tags: php, templates, symfony-1.4

I've got a Symfony 1.4 app that I've inherited to maintain and update.  One thing that I'm having trouble understanding/figuring out is how to use the same template/action name for both a load and a post.

Coming from a Struts2 background, I can reuse the same action for both methods, but have a get point to a "input" method whereas a post would point to a "execute" method.  But I can't seem to find a similar workflow in Symfony.

Given that the same template is used in both a get and a post, and I would like to use the same action name, how can I specify a different method name for each type?

For example, for a login form, I would like to create a Login action, with a "input" method that basically displays the template, and upon submission, it would go to an execute method to validate the data before redirecting or redisplaying the form with the errors.

I realize that I could put in an if ($request->isMethod('POST')) at the top of my execute method, but I presume there must be a better/more conventional way of doing this.  I presume that there must be something in symfony to allow for this, but I just haven't been able to find it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is Routing.  You can route HTTP Request Methods in Symfony.

Here's the documentation: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/10-Routing

An example of what you would like to do would be structured like this:

```
login_input:
    url:  /login
    class: sfRequestRoute
    param: { module: login, action: input }
    requirements: { sf_method: get }

login_execute:
    url:  /login
    class: sfRequestRoute
    param: { module: login, action: execute }
    requirements: { sf_method: post }
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks!  Is this the typical/conventional way one uses Symfony, or is there a different recommended approach?

Comment: This is the recommended approach.

Comment: I just noticed one thing in your configuration; the module name is the "action" (ie: login/logout/etc).  Which means that I can no longer group multiple actions together, since each are separated into individual modules.  For instance, I usually like to group login, logout, password reset in one package called "security".  But now, it appears that I have to have each one in an separate module/directory.  Is there any way to group them together?